# Get WMS service properties for cql filtering?

Tags: wms, cql-filter

From a `wms` service I know its url and a layer name called: `CATAST_Pol_Municipio`

https://idena.navarra.es/ogc/wms

I need to apply a cql_filter on a GetMap request on that layer, filtering by national cadastral reference. Tried `cql_filter=nationalCadastralReference=xxxxxxxx` but it says that there is no property with `nationalCadastralReference` name.

> Rendering process failed PropertyDescriptor is null - did you request
>   a property that does not exist?

How can I know the wms properties that I can filter the request with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. Ask the related WFS for a description of the featureType using `https://idena.navarra.es/ogc/wfs?request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=CATAST_Pol_Municipio&version=1.1.0` which returns:

   ```
    <xsd:complexContent>                                                        
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">                            
        <xsd:sequence>                                                          
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FEATURE" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CMUNICIPIO" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MUNICIPIO" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MUNINOAC" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GEOM_AREA" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GEOM_PERI" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="BEGINLIFE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>                                                         
      </xsd:extension>                                                          
    </xsd:complexContent>                                                          </xsd:complexType>
   ```
2. Ask for a feature using GetFeatureInfo and look at the returned attributes: